# Adding integers in a list iteratively to another list

Tags: python, append

I am trying to do the following (composites applications) with Python:
I have a list of names which I would like to add integers in string form to the end of each name. This is the desired outcome:

**List of names:**
Name1_, Name2_, Name3_

**List of integers:**
[45,90,45,0]

**Desired outcome:**
Name1_45, Name2_90, Name3_45, Name4_0

**Instead, this is what I'm getting:**

Name1_45, Name2_45, Name3_45, Name4_45

Name1_90, Name2_90, Name3_90, Name4_90

Name1_45, Name2_45, Name3_45, Name4_45

Name1_0, Name2_0, Name3_0, Name4_0

**Here's my code:**

```
import csv
name_list_a = []
name_list_b = []
name_angle_a = []
lam_a = 'Lam1_'
lam_b = 'Lam2_'
for i in range(1,10,1):
    name_list_a.append([lam_a + str(i) + '_'])
    # print(name_list_a)
stack_seq = [45,90,45,0]
for j in stack_seq:
    for z in name_list_a:
        name_angle_a.append([z + [str(j)]])
    print(name_angle_a)

file = open('names.txt', 'w+', newline='')
with file:
    write = csv.writer(file)
    write.writerows(name_angle_a)
```

How can I do this (if at all)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate over both lists *at the same time*, not using a nested loop. In python, you do this with `zip()`:

```
for j, z in zip(stack_seq, name_list_a):
    name_angle_a.append(z + str(j))

print(name_angle_a)
```

Comment: This really helped! What if I have more than 4 name values and just want to keep repeating the stacking sequence? For example: Name1_45, Name2_90, Name3_45, Name4_0, Name6_45, Name7_90, Name8_45, Name9_0 etc etc

Comment: Then you're going to have to either 1. iterate over just the `name_list_a` list and calculate the index of the `stack_seq` item you want (for example using the modulo operator) or 2. Tile the `stack_seq` list as many times as you need so that it's got the same number of elements as `name_list_a` @sirensoftware

Comment: Awesome, the tile command did exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You have not mentioned the language you've used. By seeing your code I can find the place it went wrong.

```
for j in stack_seq:
    for z in name_list_a:
        name_angle_a.append([z + [str(j)]])
        print(name_angle_a)
```

You have put a nested loop in the above lines, which causes printing multiple lines as in your output.
Follow the below format. Get the idea and adjust the syntax according to the programming language you use.
Just use only 1 loop as following.

```
for i in range(1,10,1):
 name_list_a.append([lam_a + str(i) + '_'])
 # print(name_list_a)
stack_seq = [45,90,45,0]
j=0
for z in name_list_a:
    name_angle_a.append([z + [str(stack_seq[j])]])
    j+=1
    print(name_angle_a)
```

Comment: The question is tagged under "python" so the person doesn't need to include that they are using python.

Comment: @RIPPLR OP added the python tag after RusJ posted their answer.